# How to parse Timestamp from Firestore to Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I got this error when trying to parse a timestamp from Firestore.

[error when running the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nV0CX.png)

```
data class User(

    val id: String,
    val name: String,
    val img: String,
    val birth: Timestamp? = null
){

    constructor() : this (
        "",
        "",
        "",
        
    )
}
```

I would like to parse the Firestore date to show the user's birthday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to add a timestamp type field using an object of type `User`, then you have to define the field in the class to be of type [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and use the annotation as below:

```
@ServerTimestamp
var birth: Date? = null
//
```

When you create an object of the `User` class, there is no need to set the date. You don't have to pass anything to the constructor. Firebase servers will read the `birth` field, as it is a ServerTimestamp (see the annotation), and it will populate that field accordingly.

Otherwise, create a Map and put:

```
"birth" to FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```